# SwaggerUI - models on API Layer vs models on BUSINESS Layer

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, swagger-ui

I face a dilemma that I already understood the cause but I confess that I didn't understand how to solve it.

My models/DTO are in the business layer since I will be using them several times. I manage to detail rules through System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations but the generated documentation is in another project, and in the Swagger setup the XML that will be linked as a basis for documentation belongs to the API project.

In other words, I'm having to bring the models to the API layer to be able to document their proper use for the user and then map them to the business layer.

[image: api layer x business layer]

In the image above it is clear, I am duplicating an object from the business layer because summary and example are not obtained from the XML because they belong to another project, at the same time if I place this content in an entity of the API project itself, the model specification works as expected

```
    c.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml"));
```

Would there be another way to solve the problem or just duplicating models and performing mappings...

[image: api entity vs business entity]